# How to divide across different indices in a single dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I wasn't for sure how to ask this question, but any advice on how to approach this would be helpful. Below is an example of the problem I am encountering.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([('Isaac', 8), ('Jacob', 12), ('Adam', 4), ('Totals', 55)], columns=('Name', 'PPG'),index_col = 0)
Totals = df['Name'] == 'Totals' 
df_totals = df[Totals]
df.PPG / df_totals.PPG
```

I know I could easily just run the df_totals.PPG by itself and enter in the number, but I would like to make it to where I can enter in different data without having to go through and change the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `iat/iloc` to extract the number and then divide:

```
df.PPG / df_totals.PPG.iat[0]

#0    0.145455
#1    0.218182
#2    0.072727
#3    1.000000
#Name: PPG, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#set PPG to PPG/Total for non total rows.
df.loc[df.Name!='Totals','PPG'] /= df.loc[df.Name=='Totals','PPG'].iloc[0]

df
Out[872]: 
     Name        PPG
0   Isaac   0.145455
1   Jacob   0.218182
2    Adam   0.072727
3  Totals  55.000000
```